# How to display image title/alt in webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

Well i'm able to displat image in webview , Now i want to display it's "title" below the image .

```
string img = "<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="link/Photo_One.JPG" width="500" height="375" alt="" title="image cation need to display below" />";

String htmlData = "<html>"
                       + head
                       + "<body>"
                       + "<h1 style=font-family:tt0248m_>"+ title + "</h1>"
                       + "<P>"+ intro + "</P>"
                       +  data 
                       + "<br>"+ img
                        // LATER + intVenueString                  
                       + "</body></html>";

     web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

can any one know how to do that in webview ?

Comment: you can split image url string by '/' in script.and select last part for showing title

Comment: can u pleas explain with snipet of code ?

Answer (score 0):

try this `var caption = img.title;`

Comment: Is this a javascript ?
I have updated my code , What can can i do in this state .?

Comment: it is. try somethink like `document.write()`. You must Echo `caption`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("title=\"[^\"]*>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(img);
if(m.find()){
   String group = m.toMatchResult().group(i);
   int indexOfTitle = group.indexOf("title=\"", 0);
   indexOfTitle += 7;
   String title = group.substring(indexOfTitle, group.lastIndexOf("\""));
}
```

Your Title is in variable "title"
This will work only if title is the last parameter of your img string.